# AJAX response with weird JSON format

Tags: jquery, json

Hello I have a PHP script that looks for  all phone numbers of a user from one table then looks for his information in another one according to that phone numbers list.

PHP Script:

```
$intUserID = $_POST['intUserID_PHP']; //This is the user ID 
$arrayUserPhoneNumbers = $_POST['arrayUserPhoneNumbers'];//this is an array of all the user's phone numbers.
  try {     
        $DBC  = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname;user=$user;           password=$password");//All my DB connection is well set.
        $query1 = "SELECT phones FROM usersphones WHERE id=".$intUserID;
        $sth = $DBC->prepare($query1);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        $i = 0;
           foreach ($result as $data) {
             $query2 = "SELECT txtshare,dtzserver,adress,issue FROM tbluserinfo WHERE  phone='".$data['phones']."'";
             $sth = $DBC->prepare($query2);
             $sth->execute();
             $result2 = $sth->fetchAll();
             echo json_encode($result2);
             $i++;  
           }    
}           
catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'Error';   
}
```

This is the JQuery code I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getinfo.php",              
    dataType:'json',
    data: {arrayUserPhoneNumbers : arrayUserPhoneNumbers,intUserID : intUserID},
success: function(data) {
}
});
```

My Question is :
I'm getting a lot of rows and this is only the last one, the JSON result I'm getting from my firebug console is :

```
[
    {
        "txtshare": "F",
        "0": "F",
        "dtzserver": "2013-01-05 00:32:55.311037+00",
        "1": "2013-01-05 00:32:55.311037+00",
        "phone": "+33522988655",
        "2": "+33522988655",
        "issue": "Lost my smartphone",
        "3": "Lost my smartphone"
    }
]
```

my JSON is valid but I don't know why there is those "0","1","2" and "3" indexes with duplicate data in this result? in my table I only have txtshare, dtzserver, phone and issue fields.
I want it to be like this :

```
[
        {
            "txtshare": "F",
            "dtzserver": "2013-01-05 00:32:55.311037+00",
            "phone": "+33522988655",
            "issue": "Lost my smartphone",
        }
 ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you might see that the returning JSON contains both the key => value pair and the array index format so its upto you to choose any 1 from.
    visit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
echo "Sequential array".PHP_EOL;
$sequential = array("foo", "bar", "baz", "blong");
var_dump(
 $sequential,
 json_encode($sequential)
);

echo PHP_EOL."Non-sequential array".PHP_EOL;
$nonsequential = array(1=>"foo", 2=>"bar", 3=>"baz", 4=>"blong");
var_dump(
 $nonsequential,
 json_encode($nonsequential)
);

echo PHP_EOL."Sequential array with one key unset".PHP_EOL;
unset($sequential[1]);
var_dump(
 $sequential,
 json_encode($sequential)
);
```

OUTPUT:

Sequential array
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "baz"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "blong"
}
string(27) "["foo","bar","baz","blong"]"

Non-sequential array
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "baz"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "blong"
}
string(43) "{"1":"foo","2":"bar","3":"baz","4":"blong"}"

Sequential array with one key unset
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "baz"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "blong"
}
string(33) "{"0":"foo","2":"baz","3":"blong"}"